# In Django, how do I put a form error into my views.py?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

```
def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if len(title)  < 5:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please write more in Title.")
        return title
```

In my models.py, this is usually how I set an error form my title.

However, what if I want to do it in views.py? I want to set an error like that, except in the logic of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form errors are stored in a dictionary (ErrorDict from `django.forms.util` ) that maps field name to ErrorList class. Look at [_clean_fields](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L273) method - you would need to call your form `clean()` method, then delete appropriate field from `cleaned_data` attribute and do something like this:

```
your_form._errors[ "your_field" ] = ErrorList( [ "Your error message" ] )
```